# Can you bring your scooter on TER trains?

Tags: trains, france, scooters

I see SNCF write about using scooters in train stations but I can't find any information on whether it's allowed to bring the scooter on the trains or not. I see that [bikes are permitted](https://www.oui.sncf/aide/transport-de-votre-velo), but some texts say they are not which doesn't help me.

Can you bring trottinettes on TER trains?

Comment: My guess (but I haven't even tried looking up references) would be that as long as it's folded it's just a piece of luggage like any other, so it needs to be properly stowed and not be a nuisance for other passengers.

Comment: Does it use any kind of fuel?  (don't count electric battery as fuel).

Comment: Are you talking about a kick scooter or an electric scooter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can you bring trottinettes on TER trains?

Yes.

https://gyronews.com/prendre-le-train-avec-sa-trottinette-electrique-les-regles-a-connaitre-3152/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201010063812/https://gyronews.com/prendre-le-train-avec-sa-trottinette-electrique-les-regles-a-connaitre-3152/)):

> Alors que nous dit la SNCF ? Une trottinette est considérée comme un bagage autorisé quand ses dimensions pliées ne dépassent pas 120 x 90 cm et quand elle est rangée dans une housse. Si ces conditions sont respectées, on peut emmener avec soi sa trottinette électrique dans un TER ou un TGV sans réservation particulière et sans surcoût. La trottinette doit en revanche être rangée dans les emplacements dédiés aux bagages et ne pas entraver la circulation des autres passagers, notamment dans le couloir central.
>
> Il est également possible de voyager avec sa trottinette dans les trains OuiGO en souscrivant l’option Bagage (en supplément du billet qui n’autorise par défaut qu’un bagage à main de petites dimensions). Les conditions sont identiques en termes de dimensions (120 x 90 cm) et de housse. Une disposition supplémentaire précise que le poids total de l’ensemble ne doit pas dépasser 30 kg.

[GTranslate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%3E%20Alors%20que%20nous%20dit%20la%20SNCF%20%3F%20Une%20trottinette%20est%20consid%C3%A9r%C3%A9e%20comme%20un%20bagage%20autoris%C3%A9%20quand%20ses%20dimensions%20pli%C3%A9es%20ne%20d%C3%A9passent%20pas%20120%20x%2090%20cm%20et%20quand%20elle%20est%20rang%C3%A9e%20dans%20une%20housse.%20Si%20ces%20conditions%20sont%20respect%C3%A9es%2C%20on%20peut%20emmener%20avec%20soi%20sa%20trottinette%20%C3%A9lectrique%20dans%20un%20TER%20ou%20un%20TGV%20sans%20r%C3%A9servation%20particuli%C3%A8re%20et%20sans%20surco%C3%BBt.%20La%20trottinette%20doit%20en%20revanche%20%C3%AAtre%20rang%C3%A9e%20dans%20les%20emplacements%20d%C3%A9di%C3%A9s%20aux%20bagages%20et%20ne%20pas%20entraver%20la%20circulation%20des%20autres%20passagers%2C%20notamment%20dans%20le%20couloir%20central.%0A%3E%0A%3E%20Il%20est%20%C3%A9galement%20possible%20de%20voyager%20avec%20sa%20trottinette%20dans%20les%20trains%20OuiGO%20en%20souscrivant%20l%E2%80%99option%20Bagage%20(en%20suppl%C3%A9ment%20du%20billet%20qui%20n%E2%80%99autorise%20par%20d%C3%A9faut%20qu%E2%80%99un%20bagage%20%C3%A0%20main%20de%20petites%20dimensions).%20Les%20conditions%20sont%20identiques%20en%20termes%20de%20dimensions%20(120%20x%2090%20cm)%20et%20de%20housse.%20Une%20disposition%20suppl%C3%A9mentaire%20pr%C3%A9cise%20que%20le%20poids%20total%20de%20l%E2%80%99ensemble%20ne%20doit%20pas%20d%C3%A9passer%2030%20kg.):

> So what does SNCF tell us? A scooter is considered authorized baggage when its **folded dimensions do not exceed 120 x 90 cm and when it is stored in a bag**. If these conditions are met, you can take your electric scooter with you in a TER or TGV without any special reservation and at no extra cost. On the other hand, the scooter must be stored in the spaces dedicated to luggage and not obstruct the movement of other passengers, especially in the central corridor.
>
> It is also possible to travel with a scooter on OuiGO trains by subscribing to the Baggage option (in addition to the ticket which by default only allows one small piece of hand baggage). The conditions are identical in terms of dimensions (120 x 90 cm) and cover. An additional provision specifies that the total weight of the set must not exceed 30 kg.

Note that in French, scooter != trottinette, and scooter is [ambiguous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scooter) in English. If you ask some SNCF agent,
use the term trottinette. Scooters, using the [French meaning](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooter), aren't authorized in a train, see https://questions.sncf.com/questions/1073281-prendre-scooter-train and https://www.motoservices.com/scooter/transporter-scooter.htm

Comment: Ah, our good friends of SNCF... 2 dimensions for a 3D object :-)

Comment: @jcaron :) at least they use the metric system! And in practice that'll pretty much never check.

Comment: I don't think I have seen (m)any scooter stored in bags onboard trains...

Comment: @jcaron same, I don't recall seeing anyone doing it. Basically no pb in bringing trotinettes in a ter, regardless of dimensions, weight, packaging etc.

Comment: @jcaron 120 x 90 cm is actually only one dimension, or it would be 120 cm x 90 cm or 120 x 90 cm².  Or maybe they mean 120 × 90 cm³? :)

Comment: Interestingly, for all the snark and nitpicking, the meaning is quite clear, at least for anybody not actively trying to misconstrue it.

Comment: Ouigo says the same about trottinettes: https://www.ouigo.com/faq?question=63697-puis-je-voyager-velo-ma-trottinette

Comment: I successfully brought a trottinette on a TER/TGV after I asked the question and saw someone have one unfolded - no issues.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder thanks for sharing the link and your experience

Comment: Thanks for the last paragraph. The question really confused me.